# Check if attribute is allowed per tag

Tags: javascript, properties, exists, setattribute, createelement

I am attempting to create a program that performs many calculations and trying to reduce my dependency footprint. I will not require jQuery because I do not need to "manipulate" the DOM, but I would like the advantage of creating elements with ease.

Is there a way to determine if an attribute is legal for a given tag so that it will not be required to build a map for every case?

I could not find anything of use when searching SO and Google.

Here's a simple JSFiddle <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/Lzbt6/)</kbd> to mess around with.

```
var propMap = {
    'text' : 'innerHTML'
};

var create = function(tagName, attributes) {
    var el = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (attributes !== undefined && typeof attributes === 'object') {
        for (var prop in attributes) {
            if (propMap[prop] !== undefined) {
                el[propMap[prop]] = attributes[prop];
            } else {
                el.setAttribute(prop, attributes[prop]);
            }
        }
    }
    return el;
}

var el = create('span', { id : 'foo', class : 'bar', text : 'Hello World' });
```

Comment: cross-browser? What about custom completely made-up attributes or html5-regulated custom attributes that have the string `data-` prepended? What about deprecated attributes? Valid for what HTML-version (4.01 and/or 5)? Maybe one could extract a map from the DTD's, but what about all kinds of applets (like Flash etc)?

Comment: Because the DOM basically just allows you to add any attribute whether it's supported or not, I wouldn't know any way of validating the attributes. I'm afraid you'll have to map them all; or, since you're applying them when mentioning tag names anyway, just write it correctly in your code right away.